# Assigning column name as variable in a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I thought this would  be simple but so far I have not had luck.

Example:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
SET @CurrentDate=GETDATE()

DECLARE @Master TABLE
(
     Column1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,@CurrentDate VARCHAR(20)
)
```

If I put [ ] around the @CurrentDate, it will be passed as a string '@CurrentDate'.

Any way to do have the variable passed as a column title in a table variable?

Comment: No, this is not possible unless you use the dynamic SQL to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about just doing this?

```
DECLARE @Master TABLE (
     Column1 VARCHAR(50),
     @CurrentDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
```

I find it unlikely that you will be using a table variable across multiple days.  Also, the column itself should be a date/time of some sort, *not a string*.